# How to get the results of language identification by Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto, office-interop, language-detection

When the translation function is enabled in Outlook, I was wondering if anyone knows how to get the results of language identification of the email body.

As shown in the figure below, Outlook has a "Translate" button in the "Language" group by default, and Microsoft offers Microsoft Machine Translation in Outlook. This is designed to detect and translate the language of the body of an email. In other words, there should be information about what language the body of the e-mail is presumed to be written in.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is no trivial to get add-in results if you don't know any public  property or method for that. Try to contact add-in developers to provide public members that can be called from other add-ins.

Note, you can use the Word object model to detect the message body language. The `WordEditor` property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the `Document` class from the Word object model. So, you can use the `Document` instance in the following way:

```
With WordDocumentInstance 
 If .LanguageDetected = True Then 
 x = MsgBox("This document has already " _ 
 & "been checked. Do you want to check " _ 
 & "it again?", vbYesNo) 
 If x = vbYes Then 
 .LanguageDetected = False 
 .DetectLanguage 
 End If 
 Else 
 .DetectLanguage 
 End If 
 If .Range.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS Then 
 MsgBox "This is a U.S. English document." 
 Else 
 MsgBox "This is not a U.S. English document." 
 End If 
End With
```

The results of the `DetectLanguage` method are stored in the `LanguageID` property on a character-by-character basis. To read the `LanguageID` property, you must first specify a selection or range of text.

When applied to a `Document` object, the `DetectLanguage` method checks all available text in the document (headers, footers, text boxes, and so forth). If the specified text contains a partial sentence, the selection or range is extended to the end of the sentence.

If the `DetectLanguage` method has already been applied to the specified text, the `LanguageDetected` property is set to `True`. To reevaluate the language of the specified text, you must first set the `LanguageDetected` property to `False`.

Comment: Thank you. As you commented, it could be done using Word's functionality. I don't remember when, but there is now a "Language" group in the "Home" tab of Outlook and "Translate" button there. I was hoping to find a property to access this feature but could not find it on the MS site.

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. You can execute the ribbon button programmatically if it can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `IMultilanguage2` interface and its [DetectInputCodepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa740986(v=vs.85)) method - it returns a ranked list of all locale matches.